# How to join 2 dataframes with a not equal values of columns in R

Tags: r, join

I have 2 dataframes:

DF1:

```
 Districts                       Total
1   Berri1                       924499
2   Boyer                        635273
3   Boyer 2                      470098
4   Brébeuf                      786729
5   Christophe-Colomb            204327
6   CSC (Côte Sainte-Catherine)  449665
7   Eco-Totem - Métro Laurier    596706
8   Maisonneuve_2                862718
9   Maisonneuve_3                361726
10  Notre-Dame                   354063
11  Parc                         593997
12  PierDup                      309569
13  Pont Jacques-Cartier         271545
14  Rachel/Hôtel de Ville        750977
15  Rachel/Papineau              1047434
16  René-Lévesque                357136
17  Saint-Antoine                106950
18  Saint-Laurent/Bellechasse    1483908
19  Saint-Urbain                 371084
```

DF2:

```
    id   nom            nom_comtage      Etat          Type        
1   1  St-Urbain_1      Saint-Urbain     Existant      compteur         
2   2  Brebeuf_1        Brébeuf          Existant      compteur     
3   3  Maisonneuve_1    Maisonneuve_1    À réinstaller compteur 
4   4  Maisonneuve_2    Maisonneuve_2    Existant      compteur     
5   5  Rachel/Papineau  Rachel/Papineau  Existant      compteur     
6   6  University_1     University       Existant      compteur     
7   7  Cote-Ste-Cathe   CSC              Existant      compteur     
8   10  Jacques-Cartie  Pont Jacques-Ca  Existant      compteur
9   12  Pierre-Dupuy_1  PierDup          Existant      compteur     
10  14  St-Antoine_1    Saint-Antoine    Existant      compteur 
11  15  Viger_1         Viger            Existant      compteur 
12  17  Maisonneuve_3   Maisonneuve_3    Existant      compteur 
13  19  Piste_Notre-Dam Notre-Dame       Existant      compteur 
14  22  Parc_1          Parc             Existant      compteur 
15  23  Rachel/Hôtel-d  Rachel/Hôtel de  Existant      compteur 
16  29  Boyer_1         Boyer            Existant      compteur 
17  36  René-Lévesque_2 René-Lévesque    Existant      compteur 
21  39  St-Laurent      Saint-Laurent U- Existant      Projet-pilot
```

I need to join them by column `nom_comptage`, but the values are not exactly the same. I tried with `grepl` but I got errors.

Comment: In what way are they not exactly the same? What is different?

Comment: For example in one column I have the name CSC (Côte Sainte-Catherine) and in the second dataframe I have only CSC, so join omit this row because it is not exactly the same value.

Comment: There is no way for R to recognize it if columns are not the same, so you will need to edit the data

Comment: The [`fuzzyjoin`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fuzzyjoin/) package might be of use here.